# Graphics card issue (gt 630M)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 14.04, freeze, xserver

I've installed ubuntu 14.04 and I have a problem with the graphic card. I've a i5 processor, so it has dual and switchable graphics, intel and nvidia. The trouble comes with the nvidia driver, as when I installed the one suggested on the "driver installer" in ubuntu, when rebooting the desktop suddenly freezes. Do you know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have the same issue. I just switched the default login manager.

If you cannot access your computer at all, then after the freeze at boot press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Otherwise,  open `Softwares and Updates` > `Additional Drivers` and switch to `propertiery` and `tested` Nvidia Drivers.

In a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), or the `tty` I described above, in case of freeze,

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdm
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
$ sudo reboot
```

The gdm manager works very well. Otherwise, I recently switched back to lightdm using

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

and it's working with Nvidia drivers as well.

Hope this helps.